# How to reencode a UTF-16 byte array as UTF-8?

Tags: arrays, string, rust, encoding

I have a UTF-16 byte array (`&[u8]`) and I want to decode and reencode it to UTF-8 in Rust.

In Python I can do this:

```py
array.decode('UTF-16', errors='ignore').encode('UTF-8')
```

How can I do this in Rust?

Comment: [`String::from_utf16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16)

Comment: @cdhowie This takes `&[u16]`.

Comment: @tctco The problem is that `UTF-16` is defined for 16-bit datapackets. There is no unique definition for how to interpret a byte sequence. It depends on the endianess of the system.

Comment: @Finomnis note that the Python `decode` method is able to detect the presence of a BOM as the first character and choose the correct endianness accordingly.

Comment: As Rusts `String::from_utf16` only takes `u16`, this problem is moved out from the standard library to the user.

Comment: In fact, I'm also new to encoding and decoding :( I'm actually a little confused why `std::str::from_utf8` still seems to work. I think the byte stream is encoded with `utf16` but the function still gives some reasonable outputs, but the length of the output string is doubled (eg len `fish.jpg` = 16)

Comment: @tctco Every other character is likely the nul character, which doesn't show up in the output. If you `println!("{:?}", the_decoded_str)` you should see all of the embedded nuls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that UTF-16 is defined for 16-bit units, and does not specify how to convert two 8-bit units (aka *bytes*) into one 16-bit unit.

For that reason, I assume that you are using *network endian* (which is *big endian*). Note that this might be incorrect, because x86 processors use *little endian*.

So the important first step is to convert the `u8`s into `u16`. In this case I will iterate over them, convert them via [`u16:from_be_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.from_be_bytes), and then collect them in a vector.

Then, we can use [`String::from_utf16()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16) or [`String::from_utf16_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16_lossy) to convert the `Vec<u16>` into a `String`.

`String`s are internally represented in Rust as UTF-8. So we can then directly pull out the UTF-8 representation via [`.as_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes) or [`.into_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes).

```
fn main() {
    let utf16_bytes: &[u8] = &[
        0x00, 0x48, 0x20, 0xAC, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00,
        0x6f, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x21,
    ];

    let utf16_packets = utf16_bytes
        .chunks(2)
        .map(|e| u16::from_be_bytes(e.try_into().unwrap()))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let s = String::from_utf16_lossy(&utf16_packets);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let utf8_bytes = s.as_bytes();
    println!("{:?}", utf8_bytes);
}
```

```
"H€llo world!"
[72, 226, 130, 172, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
```

---

Note that we have to use `.try_into().unwrap()` in our `map()` function. This is because `.chunks_exact()` doesn't let the compiler know how big the chunks are that we iterate over.

Once it is stabilized, there is the [`array_chunks()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.array_chunks) method which **does** let the compiler know, and would make this code shorter and faster.
It is sadly only available in `nightly` right now.

```
#![feature(array_chunks)]

fn main() {
    let utf16_bytes: &[u8] = &[
        0x00, 0x48, 0x20, 0xAC, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00,
        0x6f, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x21,
    ];

    let utf16_packets = utf16_bytes
        .array_chunks()
        .cloned()
        .map(u16::from_be_bytes)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let s = String::from_utf16_lossy(&utf16_packets);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let utf8_bytes = s.as_bytes();
    println!("{:?}", utf8_bytes);
}
```

```
> cargo +nightly run
"H€llo world!"
[72, 226, 130, 172, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
```

This assumes that our input is fully convertible into `u16` units. In production code, a check for an uneven number of bytes would be advisable.

---

To write this properly with error handling, I would extract it into a method and propagate errors:

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum ParseUTF16Error {
    #[error("UTF-16 data needs to contain an even amount of bytes")]
    UnevenByteCount,
    #[error("The given data does not contain valid UTF16 data")]
    InvalidContent,
}

fn parse_utf16(data: &[u8]) -> Result<String, ParseUTF16Error> {
    let data16 = data
        .chunks(2)
        .map(|e| e.try_into().map(u16::from_be_bytes))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        .map_err(|_| ParseUTF16Error::UnevenByteCount)?;

    String::from_utf16(&data16).map_err(|_| ParseUTF16Error::InvalidContent)
}

fn main() {
    let utf16_bytes: &[u8] = &[
        0x00, 0x48, 0x20, 0xAC, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00,
        0x6f, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x21,
    ];

    let s = parse_utf16(utf16_bytes).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let utf8_bytes = s.as_bytes();
    println!("{:?}", utf8_bytes);
}
```

```
"H€llo world!"
[72, 226, 130, 172, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration!!!!!! For people who wish to use little-endian, there is also a function named `u16::from_le_bytes`.

Comment: BOM support could be added to this by reading the two first bytes of the array. If we have 0xFE, 0xFF it means this is UTF-16 Big Endian. If we have 0xFF, 0xFE, then it's Little Endian. Any other value would imply we should use the current platform's endianness.

Comment: @SirDarius This would break the input I have in my examples, because my platform is x86, so this would be little endian. UTF-16 code generated by Rust will never run into this problem, because [`.encode_utf16()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.encode_utf16) returns `u16`. That means, any UTF-16 `&[u8]` must come from an external source, like a file or a network resource, and is therefore most likely encoded in network endianess. So I think big endian is a reasonable assumption to make.

Comment: It's fair to say that without a BOM, interpretation is left to the reader so yes it's ok to assume BE (and it is the recommendation from  RFC 2781). However, if we are aiming at full compatibility with the equivalent Python code, BOM support is necessary. From my experience, the assumption that UTF-16 files and character streams are Big Endian by default breaks as soon as we are dealing with data coming from Windows.

Comment: Sure. Just saying that your suggestion is wrong. You can't just assume it's the platform endianess if the first two bytes are not a combination of `0xFE` or `0xFF`. There are many network strings that would be misinterpreted then. Either way, I'd leave that up to the reader to figure out. I think this response is convoluted enough.

Comment: Note you don't need the `::<2>` for `array_chunks()`, the compiler can infer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, [WinSafe](https://crates.io/crates/winsafe) library has [`WString::from_wchars_slice`](https://docs.rs/winsafe/latest/winsafe/struct.WString.html#method.from_wchars_slice) method, which does exactly what you want.

Once you have the `WString` object, you can call [`WString::to_string`](https://docs.rs/winsafe/latest/winsafe/struct.WString.html#method.to_string) to convert it to an ordinary Rust [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html), which is UTF-8 encoded.